# Issue with DIV positions

Tags: html, css

would you know why my red div (.block) is placed above the blue wrapper and not within? Also would expect the text to be within the red DIV as well. Thanks http://jsfiddle.net/B3CL6/

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper blue-background ">
    <div class="block width100">
        <div class="block-left">
                 <h3>Block left </h3>
        </div>
        <!-- End DIV block-left -->
        <div class="block-right">
             <h1>block right</h1>

        </div>
        <!-- End DIV block-right -->
    </div>
    <!-- End DIV block width100 -->
</div>
<!-- End wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.block {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    background-clip: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background: red;
}
.width100 {
    width: 100%;
}
.top {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.blue-background {
    background: #124191;
}
.block-left {
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
.block-right {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It is within in. Try making the red background semi-transparent, and you will see that there is blue behind it.

Comment: It is inside. Its height is less than that of the blue box, so you can still see the blue box behind it.

Comment: I adding padding to the parent and you can see that the red div is inside the blue div, http://jsfiddle.net/B3CL6/1/.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B3CL6/2/

Comment: Thanks guys, but how come my text is not within the red DIV then? thanks

Comment: your text is floating.  You need a clearfix on the red div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understand is you want the Red Block inside the Blue Block. if so

try this. set the padding-top:10px to Padding:10px

```
 .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and if you want the text inside that do something like this or add another style for the "Block Right" text

```
H1{
   display: inline; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Red div(`.block`) is actually present inside Blue div(`.wrapper`). As suggested by JoshC you can check it by making your red background as semi-transparent.

To get the text to be within the red DIV, 
Remove `overflow: hidden;` property from `.wrapper` class and add it to `.block` class.
That should solve your problem.